# Sometimes the div doesn't get scrolledTop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So I'm trying to create my own chat with support to offline messages.
I can use it already, but sometimes when I send a message, the scroll doesn't move as it should, and if I want to see the message I just sent I have to scroll down a little bit. It keeps having different behavior everytime and that's what bothers me.
this is the script responsible for the scrolling whenever I send a message

```
success: function () {
                //do something with response
                var url = '/Chat/ReturnTeacherNewMessages?Student_id=' + '@ViewBag.Student_id';
                $('#user_content').load(url);
                $('#MSG').val("");
                $.ajax({
                    success: function () {
                        var wtf = $('#user_content');
                        height = wtf[0].scrollHeight;
                        wtf.scrollTop(height);
                    }
                })
            }
```

Comment: try with setTimeout or use proper jQuery height function, imo.

Comment: Scrolling whenever you send a message? Please explain or show us the desired result you seek. Oh, and welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help, I was able to solve this issue
this is what I did

```
 success: function () {
                //do something with response
                var url = '/Chat/ReturnTeacherNewMessages?Student_id=' + '@ViewBag.Student_id';
                $('#user_content').load(url);
                $('#MSG').val("");
                $.ajax({
                    success: function () {
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            var wtf = $('#user_content');
                            height = wtf[0].scrollHeight;
                            wtf.scrollTop(height);
                        }, 1000);

                    }
                })
            }
```

I know that maybe it's not the best solution, but it's the only thing that works untill now, and it works perfectly. I just need to force the thread to wait for a bit before scrollingTop.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Jquery? try using .scrollTop [API](https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/)

in your case it should look something like this :

`$('#user_content').scrollTop(0);`

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
   $('#user_content').load(url, function(){
        $(this).scrollTop($(this).height());
    });
```